# Is there any way to write PNG in segments, or other way to generated large png on Android

Tags: android, bitmap, png

I have an application, it use canvas to draw something. I want to save it as a png file. I use this code:

```
val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

// draw something

val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
...
```

It works. But sometimes the size of a bitmap can be very large, this may result in not enough memory to create the bitmap.

I would like to ask if there is any way to write png in segments. This way I can create multiple small-sized bitmaps individually and recycle them as soon as I'm done using them, just like:

```
create section1 bitmap
write section1 bitmap to png file
section1 bitmap recycle

create section2 bitmap
write section2 bitmap to png file
section2 bitmap recycle
...
```

I don't know if this is possible, or if there is another way to do this. Sorry for my bad English.